# Yet Another Liars

Tags: riddle, poetry

> I am an unobtanium.
>   Yet I am everwhere.
>   My number is avoided.
>   Yet myself is praised.
>
> After me, glass products formed.
>   Before me, clorophyll formed.
>   Above me, is where the hole is on.
>   Below me, is what I was usually befriended with.
>
> A countries of love praise me.
>   A countries of sticks praise me.
>   A broken countries praise me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Aluminum, elemental number 13

My number is avoided.

> Unlucky number 13

After me, glass products formed

> Next element is Silicon, which is what glass is made of

Before me, chlorophyll formed.

> Previous element is Magnesium, which is the core of chlorophyll

Above me, is where the hole is on.

> Boron is used in semi-conductors as holes for electrons

Below me, is what I was usually befriended with.

> Gallium is in the same group as Aluminum

Comment: but what about the title?

Comment: Perhaps this is centered around LIAR=AL+IR or LIARS=AL+RIS, or something similar, with AL=Aluminium.

Comment: No, it's actually simpler than that.

Comment: Aluminium is an atom and atom is liar.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan how can an atom be a liar?

Comment: @manshu because [it makes everything](http://www.businessinsider.com/15-jokes-only-a-chemist-will-get-2013-10?IR=T&r=US&IR=T)